# What test is this am I missing something?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n = 0}{5n^{3}  \over 2n^{3} +1}$$

$$ {5n^{3}  \over 2n^{3} +1}<$$$${5n^{3}  \over 2n^{3} } <$$
$$ {5 \over {2} }\ne 0$$

so the series is divergent but what test is this? am I missing something?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Comment: I usually just call it the *divergence test*.

Comment: Or the "if the terms don't go to zero it doesn't converge" test and, no, you aren't missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here, first I think there is a typo in your last limit sentence. The 3 should be a 2. Second, this is not a clean way of establishing that the answer is divergent. Leaving off the 1 is not very proper. Dividing every term by $n^3$ and then take the limit is a better way

Comment: The OP just changed so that the limits you were referring to disappeared.

Comment: So if I do that what test would it be? is it the limit comparison test or direct?

Comment: Yep, you are right here, but in my opinion, dividing by $n^3$ is still a solid way to determine this limit and as far as I know, endorsed in calc 1

Comment: @Itzel. None of the sort. You have essentially shown that the "sequence" does not converge to zero. This is a needed condition for a series to be convergent. So when the sequence does not converge to zero, it ends all here.

Comment: @imranfat would it be the nth-term test?

Comment: It's not a real name, but essentially, yes that's what you do, you are "taking a look" at the nth term of the sequence

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the sum diverges.  For large $n$, each term is about $\frac 52$.  The logic of your steps is not clear at all.  Some words would help.  It appears you are using a theorem that says the limit of the terms must be zero for the sum to converge, but you don't say that.